# Hi, how to increase the margin between the logo and the text?

Tags: visualforce, css

I want to give a space between the logo and the text, but neither the margin nor the padding will do it... if anyone can give you an idea, thank you
VFP:

```
<div class="header">
    <div align="center" >
        <div  align="right">Página <span class="pagenumber" /> de <span class="pagecount"/></div>
        <apex:image id="logo" width="240" height="55" value="{!$Resource.logo}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

static resource:

```
@page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin-top: 2.5cm;
        margin-left: 1.2cm;
        margin-right: 1.2cm;
        margin-bottom: 1.8cm;

        @top-center {
            content: element(header);
        }
        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footer);
        }
    }
    
    body{
        font-family: sans-serif;        
    }

    div.header {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        position: running(header);
    }

    div.footer {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        position: running(footer);
        margin-bottom: 1.8cm;

    }

    .pagenumber:before {
        content: counter(page);
    }

    .pagecount:before {
        content: counter(pages);
    }
```

Comment: Try this one. The first answer and have a look at the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693224/how-do-i-right-align-div-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not clear how your elements are positioned.

As is, there is nothing in your styling that indicates that there should be any padding or a margin between your "text" and your "image" so it's not clear what issue you are facing.

Assuming your elements are placed horizontally, you can either add a right padding to
`<div  align="right">Página <span class="pagenumber" /> de <span class="pagecount"/></div>`

or a left padding to your logo.

If you can update your post with how and what you have tried, alongside an image, it would further help narrow down the issue.